# Invalid access to memory location - Thrown by one application using a DLL but not another

Tags: c++, dll, com

I have a C++ DLL that I'm trying to run with a 3rd party application. The DLL loads and works as expected when it's used by my test application. However, the 3rd party application cannot load the DLL and gives the following error:

```
Invalid access to memory location
```

This is when using the DLL on Windows XP embedded, with the DLL using a platform toolset of v141_xp and a Windows SDK version of 7.0.

Any suggestions as to why the 3rd party application might be throwing this error? (Unfortunately it doesn't give any more detail than the above.)

Comment: Debug build; set 3rd party app as the app to be run for the dll; run under the debugger. When it breaks inspect the stack frame(s).  You can also do this for a release build so long as you have created the .PDB file in the release build.

Comment: Time to break out the debugger.

Comment: I'd look at calling conventions. You might be assuming one thing and the other application is assuming something different.

Comment: It's likely to be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641480/simple-dll-created-in-visual-studio-2017-doesnt-load-in-xp)