# Simple DLL created in Visual Studio 2017 doesn't load in XP

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017, windows-xp, static-variables

Platform Toolset - Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)

Runtime library - Multi-threaded (no CRT dependencies)

DLL loads fine on Vista+, but fails on XP SP2 (x86) with error code ERROR_NOACCESS (Invalid access to memory location)

dll code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            static std::string test;
            break;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

exe code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"dll.dll");

    if (hModule)
        MessageBoxA(0, "It works", "Info", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    else
    {
        char buff[10];
        _itoa_s(GetLastError(), buff, 10, 10);

        MessageBoxA(0, buff, "GetLastError()=", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Same problem for Visual Studio 2015. Though it works fine when compiled in **Visual Studio 2013**.

[Download VS017 solution](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0h4hpmyjbjgpqpi/DllCrashXP.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP has this restriction. When you load a DLL with `LoadLibrary`, that particular DLL cannot have a `static` data inside the DLL. It cannot be solved. You need to find another approach.

Comment: Any reference link? The same code compiled in VS2013 still works on XP.

Comment: Please search on/similar to: "loadlibrary windows xp static variable vs 2017"

Comment: Thanks for the right direction. It can be though solved via the /Zc:threadSafeInit- compiler switch (available in VS2015/2017) [More info on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517234/access-violation-on-static-initialization)

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify, that compiler switch _disables_ thread-safe initialisers (which are horrible things anyway, IMO, they should be opt-in rather than opt-out, but never mind).

Comment: And to further clarify, static _data_ is fine, but not an obect whose constructor needs to be called.